# Is there a way to read a pointer without doing a query

Tags: react-native, pointers, parse-platform, back4app

I am trying to read a pointer attached to an object in react native. I was wondering if something like this was possible `book.get('publisher').get('name')`
Or what the best way to read info from a pointer object is.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. You can do that. But you need to make sure you have used `include` function to include the pointer on your query. Something like this:

```js
const query = new Parse.Query('Book');
query.include('publisher');
const book = await query.get(bookId);
const publisherName = book.get('publisher').get('name');
```